# VBA Code to generate a dynamic excel formula

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a script that inserts a new row into the table I have in an Excel sheet. There is formulas in the sheet from the range H:L. This formula compares some values against the previous cells.
The first row in the table contains this formula

```
*H8: =IF(A8<>"",IF(C8<>"",(1-C8),1),"")
I8: =IF(A8<>"",IF(D8<>"",(1-D8),1),"")*
```

and so on to L8.
The second row and any new rows getting added below should have this formula

```
*L9 =IF(A9<>"",IF(G9<>"",L8*(1-G9),IF(L8<>"",L8,"")),"")
L10=IF(A10<>"",IF(G10<>"",L9*(1-G10),IF(L9<>"",L9,"")),"")
L11=IF(A11<>"",IF(G11<>"",L10*(1-G11),IF(L10<>"",L10,"")),"")
L12=IF(A12<>"",IF(G12<>"",L11*(1-G12),IF(L11<>"",L11,"")),"")*
```

... and so on.
My VBA script works well to insert the row and to copy the formulas to the new row... but the formula is always =IF(A9<>"",IF(G9<>"",L8*(1-G9),IF(L8<>"",L8,"")),"") , and not dynamic to change the cell references based on the new row. Below is the code I have. Not sure what is wrong in it. Is there a way someone can help please

[image]

```
Sub InsertNewRow()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim newRow As ListRow
    Dim password As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim newRowNumber As Long
    
    ' Set the password for protection
    password = "12345"
    
    ' Set the worksheet that contains the table
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Template") ' Replace "Template" with the actual sheet name
    
    ' Set the table (replace "Table2" with the actual table name)
    Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("Table2")
    
    ' Check if the worksheet is protected
    If ws.ProtectContents Then
        ' Unprotect the worksheet with the provided password
        ws.Unprotect password
    End If
    
    ' Insert a new row below the last row of the table
    Set newRow = tbl.ListRows.Add
    newRowNumber = newRow.Index
    
    ' Clear the data values in the new row for columns A to G
    With newRow.Range
        .Offset(1).Resize(1, 7).ClearContents
    End With
    
    ' Set formulas for columns H to L in the new row with adjusted references
    For i = 1 To 5
        newRow.Range.Cells(1, 7 + i).Formula = Replace(tbl.ListColumns(7 + i).DataBodyRange.Cells(newRowNumber - 1).Formula, "$A$9", "A" & newRowNumber)
        newRow.Range.Cells(1, 7 + i).Formula = Replace(newRow.Range.Cells(1, 7 + i).Formula, "$G$9", "G" & newRowNumber)
        newRow.Range.Cells(1, 7 + i).Formula = Replace(newRow.Range.Cells(1, 7 + i).Formula, "$L$8", "L" & (newRowNumber - 1))
        newRow.Range.Cells(1, 7 + i).Formula = Replace(newRow.Range.Cells(1, 7 + i).Formula, "$L" & (8 + i - 1), "L" & newRowNumber)
    Next i
    
    ' Protect the worksheet back with the provided password
    If ws.ProtectContents Then
        ws.Protect password
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What's formula in H9:K9?

Comment: H9 =IF(A9<>"",IF(D9<>"",I8*(1-D9),IF(I8<>"",I8,"")),"")
I9 =IF(A9<>"",IF(D9<>"",I8*(1-D9),IF(I8<>"",I8,"")),"")
J9 =IF(A9<>"",IF(E9<>"",J8*(1-E9),IF(J8<>"",J8,"")),"")
K9 =IF(A9<>"",IF(F9<>"",K8*(1-F9),IF(K8<>"",K8,"")),"")
L9 =IF(A9<>"",IF(G9<>"",L8*(1-G9),IF(L8<>"",L8,"")),"")

Comment: I have updated the code and formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- A small modification to the formula would make it easier to fill or copy down to multiple cells in the worksheet.

> H8: =IF(**$A8**<>"",IF(C8<>"",(1-C8),1),"")

> I8: =IF(**$A8**<>"",IF(D8<>"",(1-D8),1),"")

> L9: =IF(**$A9**<>"",IF(G9<>"",L8*(1-G9),IF(L8<>"",L8,"")),"")

- You don't have to set formula on inserted row (except row 9) if the formula is same as above.. The formula in ListObject will automatically fill it.

```vb
Sub InsertNewRow()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim newRow As ListRow
    Dim password As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim newRowNumber As Long
    Application.AutoCorrect.AutoFillFormulasInLists = False
    ' Set the password for protection
    password = "12345"
    ' Set the worksheet that contains the table
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Template") ' Replace "Template" with the actual sheet name
    ' Set the table (replace "Table2" with the actual table name)
    Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("Table2")
    ' Check if the worksheet is protected
    If ws.ProtectContents Then
        ' Unprotect the worksheet with the provided password
        ws.Unprotect password
    End If
    ' Insert a new row below the last row of the table
    Set newRow = tbl.ListRows.Add
    ' Get row number with Range.Row
    newRowNumber = newRow.Range.Row
    ' Clear the data values in the new row for columns A to G
    Cells(newRowNumber, 1).Offset(1).Resize(1, 7).ClearContents
    ' Set formula with FormulaR1C1
    ' Set formulas for columns H to L in the new row with adjusted references
    If newRowNumber > 8 Then
        Cells(newRowNumber, "H").Resize(1, 5).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC1<>"""",IF(RC[-5]<>"""",R[-1]C*(1-RC[-5]),IF(R[-1]C<>"""",R[-1]C,"""")),"""")"
    End If
    ' Protect the worksheet back with the provided password
    If ws.ProtectContents Then
        '        ws.Protect password
    End If
End Sub
```

Row 10 is inserted with code.
[image]

Comment: Sorry, the formula that is getting added to the new row is 
H9 =IF(A3<>"",IF(C9<>"",H8*(1-C9),IF(H8<>"",H8,"")),"")
H10 =IF(A3<>"",IF(C9<>"",H8*(1-C9),IF(H8<>"",H8,"")),"")

Comment: I finally understand your scenario. The code should insert formulas on row 9 coz its formula is different with above row. Please try revised code.

Comment: The code didn't work. The formula it inserted in H11 is

'=IF($A10<>"",IF(C10<>"",H9*(1-C10),IF(H9<>"",H9,"")),"")'

Correct code should be 

'=IF($A11<>"",IF(C11<>"",H10*(1-C11),IF(H10<>"",H10,"")),"")'

Comment: Please check the formula on row 10. The existing errors in row 10's formula could propagate when filling down. To avoid this scenario, you can update one line code `If newRowNumber > 8 Then`. But you have to make sure all formulas are correct to get the right values on worksheet.

Comment: the formula is correct and is pasting correctly in H10, but from H11, it is wrong.

Comment: If you test the code with `If newRowNumber = 9 Then`, the formula of H11 is filled by H10. The code didn't overwrite it. I would suggest to try clearing out all rows after `row 8` first. Then run the code again which inserts the new rows one by one. Hope you could get what you are looking for.

Comment: I tried changing 'If newRowNumber = 9 Then' but it doesn't work. Is there any other approach to handle this?

Comment: What did you change with the code? Please show the formula of last row before run testing and the formula which insert by code on your post. It will be helpful to find the root cause.

Comment: I changed the
    If newRowNumber = 8 Then
to
    If newRowNumber = 9 Then

When I do that, the formula pasted on row 10 is correct, however, from row 11 it is wrong.

The formulas I have currently are
    H8 =IF($A8<>"",IF(C8<>"",(1-C8),1),"")
    H9 =IF($A9<>"",IF(C9<>"",H8*(1-C9),IF(H8<>"",H8,"")),"")
H10 should have the formula same as H9, but with updated cell references, like this
=IF($A10<>"",IF(C10<>"",H9*(1-C10),IF(H9<>"",H9,"")),"")

I assume you're already aware the formula in H8 is different to H9 as H8 doesn't have a previous row to compare value

Comment: I don't think I posed that code. It was ` If newRowNumber = 9`. The lasted version is  `If newRowNumber > 8 Then`.

Comment: Is this the section you're referring to from the above code?
If newRowNumber > 8 Then
        Cells(newRowNumber, "H").Resize(1, 4).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC1<>"""",IF(RC[-5]<>"""",R[-1]C*(1-RC[-5]),IF(R[-1]C<>"""",R[-1]C,"""")),"""")"
    End If

Comment: I add a code line to disable `AutoFillFormulasInLists`. I have tested it to insert row 9 ,and row 10. Hope it will fix the bug on your pc.

Comment: This solution is working. I started from scratch and added the formula and code you provided and somehow it worked. Thanks so much.

Comment: @Jo365 Good to konw.